# Could not import settings (is it on sys.path?) - Django

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a good idea of what's wrong. There are numerous reports of this online. It's most likely got to do with the system path of my settings.py because I moved my project to another computer (old project was in /srv/www/tbg, new one is in /var/www/tbg). I changed all pertinent paths; Apache-related, settings.py, django.wsgi. That said, I've tried everything I can think of. This is the most promising link I found online:

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

But I still can't figure out what's wrong in my case. This is my `django.wsgi`:

```
import os
import sys
path = '/var/www/tbg/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
#sys.path.append(path)#['/var/www/tbg'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tbg.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

made according to this doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Let me know if you need further info.

Edit: Full traceback: http://pastebin.com/6VTW2wWp

Comment: try `path = '/var/www/tbg` (no trailing slash)

Comment: I love django, but I've always felt their path structure didn't make as much sense as it could, and it doesn't help things that they changed things around and so a lot of instructions are out of date... is your settings.py in /var/www/tbg/ or /var/www/tbg/tbg.  If the former, do os.environ['DJANGO-SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

Comment: It's in /tbg/tbg/ EDIT Does it matter that I didn't actually create a project called tbg on this computer? I really didn't think it could matter, but now I'm starting to think it might.

Comment: Well, color me surprised. The old folder had no __init__.py files. What the heck? I thought that was necessary for any python framework to function. Anyways, problem is fixed.